# I need to print abc\ in input field of HTML using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print `abc\` in input field of HTML using JS.

```
<p id="pid"></p>
<script>
var a ='abc\';//this is required output of my input, not abc\\
document.getElementById("pid").innerHTML=a.replace("\","\\");
</script>
```

This is showing as an unexpected error. So, how I can get this value (`abc\`) in input, or any other place using `document`?

Comment: Your code is a syntax error.  Learn about string escaping.

Comment: user inputting abc\  in input field, so i want to save it in js var. so please say me, is there any way to do it.

Comment: That just works.  You don't need to do anything.  You need to learn what escaping actually means.

Comment: what do u means by ' that just works' .  if you are making a aform, if you are allowing all symboles,  and then show it in next page.  if one user put abc\  then , what you will do.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  You don't actually have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape `\` by using `\\`.

```
var a ='abc\\';
```

Comment: how to change   'abc\'  to  'abc\\'

Comment: Just write abc\\\\ then.

Comment: user can put anything, right.  so he is putting abc\  , how to make it abc\\\\. that is problem